# multiple if without else not equivalent to if else? c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

Trying to sort a vector of 0,1,2's in ascending order. I thought the following two are equivalent:

```
void sortColors(vector<int>& nums) {
    int i=0,j=nums.size()-1;
    int k=0;
    while (k<=j){
        if (nums[k]==0){
            swap(nums[i],nums[k]);
            ++i;
            ++k;
        } 
        else if (nums[k]==1) {
            ++k;
        }
        else if (nums[k]==2){
            swap(nums[j],nums[k]);
            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
void sortColors(vector<int>& nums) {
    int i=0,j=nums.size()-1;
    int k=0;
    while (k<=j){
        if (nums[k]==0){
            swap(nums[i],nums[k]);
            ++i;
            ++k;
        }
        if (nums[k]==1) ++k;
        if (nums[k]==2){
            swap(nums[j],nums[k]);
            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

However, only the first is correct. When test running nums={2,0}, the first one does the correct ordering while the second function does nothing. What are the difference here?

Comment: They are not equivalent because k and nums[k] changes.

Comment: _"What are the difference here?"_ - the contents of the compound block of the previous `if` statement changes the indexes. This will eventually lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: It pays to step through with pen and paper in the early days of learning.

Comment: `if... else` means that if the first condition is true, then the `else` branch is not executed.  `if... if` means that both tests are executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not the same, because you change the variable that you use for the condition:

```
while (k<=j){
    if (nums[k]==0){              
        swap(nums[i],nums[k]);
        ++i;
        ++k;
    }
    if (nums[k]==1) ++k;         // if num[k] == 1
    if (nums[k]==2){             // now k isnt 
                                 // the same as for the last condition
        swap(nums[j],nums[k]);
        --j;
    }
}
```

while with the `if-else` version only one of the branches is executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in the output to be sure but that isn't what you need to know.  What you need to know is this:

Multiple if statements means that there is a chance that each of the if blocks has a chance to be executed.  So, if you have N conditions then 0 to N blocks will execute.

```
int a = 0;
if(a == 0)
    a++;
if(a == 1)
    a++;
if(a == 2)
    a++;
if(a == 3)
    a++;
```

All of these will execute and a will be 4.

A single line of if/else if/else statements means that only one of the blocks will ever execute each time you use them.  So, if you have N conditions then only a single one of those blocks will execute.

```
int a = 20;
if(a == 0)
    a++;
else if(a == 1)
    a++;
else if(a == 2)
    a++;
else
    a = 0;
```

Only the else block will execute so a will be 0

Lastly, a line of if/else if statements means that AT MOST one block will execute.  There is a chance that none of them will execute as you don't have a final else statement to catch "everything else".  So, if you have N conditions then 0 or 1 of those blocks will execute.

```
int a = 20;
if(a == 0)
    a++;
else if(a == 1)
    a++;
else if(a == 2)
    a++;
else if(a == 3)
    a++;
```

None of these execute so a remains 20

Comment: Thanks for the careful explanation. It looks like in most scenario we will be using the complete if else statement so that exactly one of the branch will be run. Using multiple if without else can be dangerous and confusing especially the do something part involves modifying the number that enters the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent. Because second `if()` will be executed after first if, it might fire if k was changed inside first if. This would never happen with `else if`, since `else` would never fire if first `if` fired.